# How to fix "namespace std has no member scoped_lock" error in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, c++17

I'm learning multithreading now and want to use std::scoped_lock, but Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 shows error message saying

> namespace "std" has no member "scoped_lock"

I made sure that I'm using C++17 by right click project name -> Properties -> C/C++ -> Language -> C++ Language Standard -> /std:c++17.
I searched google, but couldn't find any solution.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <string>
#include <thread>

void PrintMessage(const std::string& message)
{
    static std::mutex sMutex;
    std::scoped_lock<std::mutex> lock(sMutex);
    std::cout << message << std::endl;
}
```

I want to use std::scoped_lock without error message.

Comment: Which version of 2017 are you using?

Comment: According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support#cpp17, you need at least VS 2017 15.3

Comment: It seems like I'm using version 15.9.7

Comment: I solved this problem. Don't type /std:c++17. Just choose 'ISO C++17 Standard (/std:c++17)' from options.